# Design of moderator view of flags, deleted comments and timeline on questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, moderator-tools

Moderators, and maybe users with high enough reputation, are presented with additional information concerning flags, deleted comments, and the timeline of questions and answers in a box off to the side:

[image: comment deletion image]

This is a very useful feature for moderators, but when the window width is reduce to 1050 pixels or less, the box disappears and there is no easy way to access the information. For a narrow range of widths the box is represented as an * which lets you expand it. I would like to see a redesign where the information remains easily accessible for small screen widths. I am not a graphics designer, but maybe moving the * above/below the votes/accepted answer information for screen resolutions less than 1050 pixels would work.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure a redesign is really necessary. There are already ways to access this information if the options on the side of your screen do not appear, the "fallback" if you will - through the mod menu itself. That's your * button.

[image: Mod menu]

The "show *n* deleted comments" option will appear any time the post actually has deleted comments to show. Currently, selecting it and clicking submit will take you to a separate page where all the comments for the post are displayed in order, including the deleted ones. It would be nice if they could modify this behavior to simply load the deleted comments inline with the rest of the comments on the page like the other option (especially since that other page does not have an undelete button for comments deleted by a moderator).

You can also visit the moderator timeline to get the full history of the post, which will include the deleted comments intermingled between other events.

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of the other options allow you to undelete a comment, which is what the real issue for me is.

Comment: @StrongBad I suggested in my answer that the "show *n* deleted comments" option be changed to just load them inline. But I don't think moving that box anywhere else for smaller screens is necessary when we already have a button right there that's *always* visible. A * button doesn't achieve anything that the mod button wouldn't already achieve. The whole point of that box over there was quick display of information. That functionality is lost if you collapse it in any way.

Comment: @StrongBad The "show X deleted comments" menu option brings up a view that shows an "undelete" link in the DeletionDate column for comments that can be undeleted.

Comment: @AnnaLear [I don't see one.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P0bE6.png) Is it supposed to be there?

Comment: @animuson Argh. Dev-only there, apparently. That should be easy enough to fix, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear that would fix my issue.

Comment: If you fix it, @anna bear in mind that the rules for devs and mods are subtly different (so the rules for display should be likewise).

Comment: @AnnaLear any though on making the change?

Answer (score 0):

Marking this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because we won't fix it until we dramatically change the design for how moderator tools are displayed.

The floating sidebar (and inline display of deleted comments) should be considered a convenience function; great for folks processing lots of stuff quickly, but not absolutely essential. The information presented there is also accessible from the mod menu / timeline - [see animuson's answer for details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245125/design-of-moderator-view-of-flags-deleted-comments-and-timeline-on-questions-an/245127#245127).

Comment: See Anna's comment, it seems like dev's see something that mod's do not.

Comment: That can be fixed if there's a real need for it.

Comment: While desktops and laptops with narrow screens are likely rare, my iPad has a resolution less than 1050 pixels wide so mods cannot currently undelete comments from presumably most tablets.

Comment: Yeah - got a more elaborate fix for that and other stupid comment things planned; soon...